# 'inode/directory' folder on my Desktop

Tags: 14.04, directory, desktop-environments, .desktop

There in an empty "Untitled Folder"('inode/directory') on my Desktop. I don't remember whether or not I created it, or its system folder.

Comment: Any folder named `Untitled Folder` is not going to be a system folder. It's very likely that you created it for something, then never used it. Or that you accidently created it.